# GAE NDB Expando Model with dynamic Kind

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Is it possible to assign a dynamic Entity Kind to an Expando Model? For example, I want to use this model for many types of dynamic entities:

```
class Dynamic(ndb.Expando):
    """
    Handles all "Post types", such as Pages, Posts, Users, Products, etc...
    """
    col = ndb.StringProperty()
    parent = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    slug = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Right now I use the "col" `StringProperty` to hold the Kind (like "Pages", "Posts", etc) and query for the "col" every time.

After reading the docs, I stumbled upon this @classmethod:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    @classmethod
    def _get_kind(cls):
         return 'AnotherKind'
```

Does that mean I can do this?

```
class Dynamic(ndb.Expando):
    """
    Handles all "Post types", such as Pages, Posts, Users, Products, etc...
    """
    col = ndb.StringProperty()
    parent = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    slug = ndb.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def _get_kind(cls):
        return 'AnotherKind'
```

But how do I dynamically replace 'AnotherKind'? Can I do something like `return col`?

Thanks!

Comment: I think (reading between the lines) you should look closely at PolyModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can do that, but it sounds dangerous, and GAE updates might break your code.

Using subclasses seems like a much safer alternative.  Something like this:

```
class Dynamic(ndb.Expando):
    parent = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    slug = ndb.StringProperty()

class Pages(Dynamic):
    pass

class Posts(Dynamic):
    pass

class Users(Dynamic):
    pass
```

You could also try using `PolyModel`.

We need to know more about your application and what you are trying to accomplish to give more specific advice.